# Find number of occurrence of given value within string?

Tags: php, regex, string

Consider a string as below .

```
$string="Lorem ipsum $ 1000 ,ipsum $2000 sopr $250 gerb $ 150 dfkuer fsdf erwer 1020 $ gsdfasdtwe qw $ 5000 efk kdfgksgdf 2000 $ sdhfgsd fsdf 620 $ sdfjg jsdf3000$";
```

I have to find out how many numbers are there within this string. But the number is equal to 1000 and above 1000 which proceed and followed by $ symbol .

Example : $1000 (or) $ 1000 (or) 1000$ (or) 1000 $ and above 1000 only .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
$string  ="Lorem ipsum $ 1000 ,ipsum $2000 sopr $250 gerb $ 150 dfkuer fsdf erwer 1020 $ gsdfasdtwe qw $ 5000 efk kdfgksgdf 2000 $ sdhfgsd fsdf 620 $ sdfjg jsdf3000$";

preg_match_all('/\$\s?(?P<pr>\d{4,})|(?P<fl>\d{4,})\s?\$/',$string,$match);
$res     = array_merge(array_filter($match['pr']),array_filter($match['fl']));

echo "<pre>";
print_r($res);
```

Output :

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1000
    [1] => 2000
    [2] => 5000
    [3] => 1020
    [4] => 2000
    [5] => 3000
)
```

Comment: Edited the answer please check it now

Comment: Thanks,Here your code its help me to solve                                             $string  ="Lorem ipsum DOLLAR 1000 ,ipsum $2000 sopr $250 gerb $ 150 dfkuer fsdf erwer 1020 $ gsdfasdtwe qw $ 5000 efk kdfgksgdf 2000 $ sdhfgsd fsdf 620 $ sdfjg jsdf3000$";

preg_match_all('/(?P<number>\DOLLAR\s?\d{4,}|\d{4,}\s?\$)/',$string,$match);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($match['number']);

Answer (score 1):

Using preg_match_all() and a foreach loop:

```
$string="Lorem ipsum $ 1000 ,ipsum $2000 sopr $250 gerb $ 150 dfkuer fsdf erwer 1020 $ gsdfasdtwe qw $ 50000 efk kdfgksgdf 2000 $ sdhfgsd fsdf 620 $ sdfjg jsdf3000$";

preg_match_all('/(\$\s?)(?P<before>\d{4,})|(?P<after>\d{4,})(\s?\$)/', $string, $m);

$tmp = array_filter($m["before"]) + array_filter($m["after"]);
$number = array();
foreach($tmp as $n){
    if($n >= 1000){
        if(isset($number[$n])){
            $number[$n]++;
        }else{
            $number[$n] = 1;
        }
    }
}

print_r($number);
// Key => number, value => n occurences
```

I've used `\d{4,}` to match 4 digit numbers which are 1000 or higher, but say for example there is a number like `0500`, this will also be matched. So I used a foreach loop to filter the numbers.

Comment: I guess this will match a number even if it is not followed or preceded by `$`

Comment: Try a string like this : `$string  ="Lorem ipsum $ 1000 ,ipsum $2000 sopr $250 gerb $ 150 dfkuer fsdf 565656 erwer 1020 $ gsdfasdtwe qw $ 5000 efk kdfgksgdf 2000 $ sdhfgsd fsdf 620 $ sdfjg jsdf3000$";` your code will output `565656` also which is not supposed to

Comment: @PrasanthBendra why not o.O ? The OP said >= 1000 !

Comment: Should be followed or preceded by `$`

Comment: @PrasanthBendra Ah yes ofcourse, you already mentioned that in the first comment. I'm working on a quick solution, thank you anyways :)

Comment: @PrasanthBendra fixed and added the n occurences principle :p

Comment: Thank you for your great effort!

Comment: Can we give multiple keyword instead of $ symbol for example $ ,Dollar and so

Comment: @tip_top Change the regex to `'/(\$\s?),?(?P<before>\d{4,})|(?P<after>\d{4,}),?(\s?\$)/'`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$string="Lorem ipsum $ 1000 ,ipsum $2000 sopr $250 gerb $ 150 dfkuer fsdf erwer 1020 $ gsdfasdtwe qw $ 5000 efk kdfgksgdf 2000 $ sdhfgsd fsdf 620 $ sdfjg jsdf3000$";
$pattern = "#([$][\s]*)?([1-9]\d{3})([\s]*[$])?#";
//(?<=$|$\s)
//(?=$|\s$)
preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $out);
print_r($out[2]);

Array
(
    [0] => 1000
    [1] => 2000
    [2] => 1020
    [3] => 5000
    [4] => 2000
    [5] => 3000
)
```

Comment: I guess this will match a number even if it is not followed or preceded by `$`